# how to reject incoming connections?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have a TCPSocket and in some cases (for example, when I get to the system limit) I want to reject new connections.

If i simply do not "accept" the connection it still in the queue...

Comment: Do you mean `TCPServer` rather than `TCPSocket`?

Answer (score 0):

Is it really in the queue ? doesn't it gets time-out and flushed ?

You might want to keep an extra buff for accepting connection and then immediately closes that, do this kind of work in other thread, so it does not affect your work. Not sure may this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Limit the listening queue by providing a number to the "listen" call. IMHO it's not possible to change it afterwards, so you might need to close and then reopen the socket.